# Sorting DataTable based on words in rows

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I am struggling with sorting records in Datatable based on number of words present in each row. Datatable will be filled with semantic library words i.e

```
Library_Column
---------------
Business 
Means 
Medium Business
Business Ways
Medium
Business Medium Descriptions
Ways
```

I would like to sort these records as following so the biggest string/row with records is used for matching.

```
Library_Column
--------------
Business Medium Descriptions
Medium Business
Business Ways
Business
Means
Ways
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a 2 columns, one to count the words, and one column with an expression to store the length of the string.  Since the options for columns with expressions are limited, we have to manually update the "WordCount" column values in a loop.

```
//Call data layer that returns your data table prior to this, 
//and then we will add our custom columns
dt.Columns.Add("WordCount", typeof(int));

foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    r["WordCount"] = r["Library_Column"].ToString().Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Length;
}

dt.Columns.Add("LenOfCol", typeof(int), "len(Library_Column)");
```

And then update the `DataTable.DefaultView.Sort` prior to databinding to sort by word count first and then string length (in the case of multiple lines with the same word count).

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "WordCount DESC, LenOfCol DESC";
```

Comment: @kashif4u I misread your question the first time.  I updated the answer to include word count as the first sort option.

Comment: Thanks BateTech. Even the first solution was good I just didn't have enough time to implement it till weekend. Cheers